# RMonkey data frame split columns

Tags: r, split, surveymonkey

I've downloaded data from SurveyMonkey using RMonkey into a data frame using the following code:

```
g <- getresponses(r, s[[1]])
g <- as.data.frame.ts(g)
temp <- edit(g)
```

Using the data editor, I can see that the data obtained for each respondent is all in one column

[view on data editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az8MY.png)

I want to be able to find pattern (question ID), make that the header of the column and return all related answer IDs for each respondent within that column.

I have a list of all the question IDs using `surveyquestions(s[[1]])`, and can count the number of times a question ID (such as "917087271") is used with `str_count(g, "917087271")` if that helps?

Sorry if I've not explained this well, but would be very grateful for any pointers!

Comment: What version of Rmonkey are you using? It will be printed in the output of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: @Thomas Rmonkey_0.3.1

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Can you file a bug report here: https://github.com/cloudyr/Rmonkey/issues